# Remove html tags from a string except <a> in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

How I can clean a string leaving only the plain text and the `<a>` elements?

Example:

```
<table><tr><td>Hello my web is <a href="http://www.myweb.com">Myweb</a>, <span>Follow my blog!</span></td></tr></table>
```

Results:

```
Hello my web is <a href="http://www.myweb.com">Myweb</a>, Follow my blog!
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you're trying to do this via RegEx (as per your tag) then remember this:  Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Comment: @freefaller looks like you got there with the "for the love of god, NO" advice before me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VERY VERY hacky (and really shouldn't be used productionally) but:

**C#**

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"<[^>]+?\/?>", m => {
    // here you can exclude specific tags such as `<a>` or maybe `<b>`, etc.
    return Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, @"^<a\b|\/a>$") ? m.Value : String.Empty;
});
```

Basically, it just takes out every HTML code with the exception of `<a ...>...</a>`.

**Note: this DOES NOT**:

- Validate if a tag was opened/closed/nested correctly.
- Validate if the `<>` are actually HTML tags (maybe your input has `<` or `>` in the text itself?)
- Handle "nested" `<>` tags. (e.g. `<img src="http://placeholde.it/100" alt="foo<Bar>"/>` will leave a remainder of `"/>` in the output string)

---

Here's the same thing turned in to a helper method:

```
// Mocks http://www.php.net/strip_tags

/// <summary>
/// Removed all HTML tags from the string and returned the purified result.
/// If supplied, tags matching <paramref name="allowedTags"/> will be left untouched.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The input string.</param>
/// <param name="allowedTags">Tags to remain in the original input.</param>
/// <returns>Transformed input string.</returns>
static String StripTags(String input, params String[] allowedTags)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
    MatchEvaluator evaluator = m => String.Empty;
    if (allowedTags != null && allowedTags.Length > 0)
    {
        Regex reAllowed = new Regex(String.Format(@"^<(?:{0})\b|\/(?:{0})>$", String.Join("|", allowedTags.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x)).ToArray())));
        evaluator = m => reAllowed.IsMatch(m.Value) ? m.Value : String.Empty;
    }
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"<[^>]+?\/?>", evaluator);
}

// StripTags(input) -- all tags are removed
// StripTags(input, "a") -- all tags but <a> are removed
// StripTags(input, new[]{ "a" }) -- same as above
```

Comment: better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This code will remove all tags but `<a>` tag.

```
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?!</a>)(<\w+>|</\w+>)");
        var removedTags = r.Replace(inputString, "");
```

Comment: FYI you could compress that in `(?!</?a>)</?\w+>`. But your regex removes `<a href>` and I don't believe it should.

Answer (score 0):

First off [you can't use regex's to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

just do a global replace on something like `</?table>|</?tr>|</?td>` with any other tags you don't want and replace them with the empty string "".